# Lazy loading procedure

Tags: linux, assembly, compilation, linker, decompiling

I would like to know how does it work precisely. 
Let's say we have the following code snippets:

```
0000000000400400 <printf@plt-0x10>:
400400:       ff 35 02 0c 20 00       pushq  0x200c02(%rip)        # 601008   <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
400406:       ff 25 04 0c 20 00       jmpq   *0x200c04(%rip)        # 601010 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
40040c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000400410 <printf@plt>:
400410:       ff 25 02 0c 20 00       jmpq   *0x200c02(%rip)        # 601018 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x18>
400416:       68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
40041b:       e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400400 <_init+0x20>

....

40053b:       e8 d0 fe ff ff          callq  400410 <printf@plt>
```

First of all the printf stub (printf@plt) is called, then the address located at 0x601018 (within the GOT) is taken in order to jump into it.

Let's say that is the first time that printf is called: the value we find will be 0x400416, that is to say the next instruction, right?

Following the code, the value 0 is pushed onto the stack and then we jump at 0x400400. Here a GOT address is pushed (0x601008) and then there a jump to the next one (0x601010): Why? What is in there exactly?

Furthermore: When exactly the dynamic linker is called and how?

Answer (score 0):

You have stopped tracing right at the answer ;)
If you look at the final pointer (`0x601010`) you should see it goes to `_dl_runtime_resolve`. The first push in the `plt` entry stores the relocation index on the stack (this identifies the entry to operate on) and the second push from the got is the link map for the module. `_dl_runtime_resolve` is typically an assembly function in the linker (for x86-64 it lives in [glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/dl-trampoline.S;h=bf3cff7b86194e00a3fcec31110e3cb2422e6410;hb=HEAD)) which, after some register-preserving, invokes `_dl_fixup` and that does all the resolving work (including updating the pointer in the GOT, so subsequent invocations go directly to the resolved function). Finally `_dl_runtime_resolve` jumps to the now resolved function so it actually gets executed too :)

Comment: Your answer lacks some details. In particular, *how* does `_dl_runtime_resolve` get to be at the final pointer? A more full-featured description of the whole process: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries/

Comment: @EmployedRussian sure, it's not a complete description, but it answers the specific questions asked by the OP. Funnily enough even your link only says "_The first PLT entry is a call to a resolver routine, which is located in the dynamic loader itself_", at least I couldn't find where it provides any more details about that.